# Amsmath pmatrix with column dividing line (rather than \begin{array})

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I know it is possible to create a matrix with a column divider using `\begin{array}`:

```latex
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
    5 & 1 & 5 & 0\\
    6 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
    0 & 3 & 4 & 1\\
\end{array}\right)
```

[image]

I am wondering whether there is some form of this possible with the `\pmatrix` command from amsmath or is using `\begin{array}` the best way in this case?

Comment: There isn't. Tip: use `@{}ccc|c@{}` then it has the same spacing as pmatrix. Pmatrix use an automated column numbers and thus there is no interface to insert the |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a fairly general method for adding whatever number of vertical bars; you need to specify the number of columns between bars, so your example would require `3|1`.

An optional argument to the defined `Xmatrix+` environments is for the alignment of columns (default `c`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ben_matrix_preamble:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { | } { #2 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { *{##1}{#1} }
  \exp_args:Ne \array{ @{} \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { | } @{} }
 }

\clist_map_inline:nn { {},b,B,p,v,V }
 {
  \use:e
   {
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1matrix+}{O{c}m}
     {
      \left\str_case:nnF { #1 } {{b}{[}{B}{\{}{p}{(}{v}{|}{V}{\|}}{.}
      \ben_matrix_preamble:nn { ##1 } { ##2 }
     }
     {
      \exp_not:N \endarray
      \right\str_case:nnF { #1 } {{b}{]}{B}{\}}{p}{)}{v}{|}{V}{\|}}{.}
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{matrix+}{3|1}
5 & 1 & 5 & 0 \\
6 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 4 & 1
\end{matrix+}
+
\begin{pmatrix+}{3|1}
5 & 1 & 5 & 0 \\
6 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 4 & 1
\end{pmatrix+}
+
\begin{bmatrix+}{3|1}
5 & 1 & 5 & 0 \\
6 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 4 & 1
\end{bmatrix+}
\]

\[
\begin{pmatrix+}{2|1|1}
5 & 1 & 5 & 0 \\
6 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 4 & 1
\end{pmatrix+}
\]
\[
\begin{pmatrix+}{3|1}
-5 &  1 & 5 & 0 \\
 6 & -2 & 2 & -2 \\
 0 &  3 & 4 & 1
\end{pmatrix+}
\ne
\begin{pmatrix+}[r]{3|1}
-5 &  1 & 5 & 0 \\
 6 & -2 & 2 & -2 \\
 0 &  3 & 4 & 1
\end{pmatrix+}
\]

\end{document}
```

This defines `matrix+`, `bmatrix+`, `Bmatrix+`, `pmatrix+`, `vmatrix+` and `Vmatrix+`, reflecting the standard `amsmath` matrix environments.

[image]

The seemingly mysterious code with `\clist_map_inline:nn` is just to avoid having to write

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{matrix+}{O{c}m}
 {
  \left.\ben_matrix_preamble:nn { ##1 } { ##2 }
 }
 {
  \endarray\right.
 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{bmatrix+}{O{c}m}
 {
  \left[\ben_matrix_preamble:nn { ##1 } { ##2 }
 }
 {
  \endarray\right]
 }
```

and so on for the other four environments.

Comment: Does this approach have a practical advantage over writing `\left(\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}} ... \end{array}\right)`?

Comment: @Mico Less characters to type (in the document)? Not having to remember `@{}` and so on?

Comment: A disadvantage, however, is toward the older LaTeX2e where `expl3` is not available... while the solution from @Mico applies for all LaTeX2e.

Answer (score 6):

For a four-column matrix *without* a vertical line,

```
\left(\begin{array}{@{}cccc@{}} ... \end{array}\right)
```

and

```
\begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix}
```

produce the *same output*. (Note the 2 instances of `@{}`.) This is not coincidence, of course, since the `[bBvVp]matrix` environments internally employ `array` environments.

Hence, I can't see a meaningful downside to setting up a four-column matrix *with* a vertical line environment as

```
\left(\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}} 
...
\end{array}
```

Again, note the `@{}` particles.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use the `pNiceArray` environment from the `nicematrix` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\(\begin{pNiceArray}{ccc|c} 
    5 & 1 & 5 & 0\\
    6 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
    0 & 3 & 4 & 1\\
\end{pNiceArray}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Additionally, you also have access to the `S` column type when loading the `siunitx` package, allow you more control over the alignment and formatting of number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\(\sisetup{table-format = 1.0}
\begin{pNiceArray}{S[table-format = +1.0] S[table-format = 2.1] S |S} 
    5 & 12.0 & 5 & 0\\
    -6 & 2.2 & 2 & 2\\
    0 & 3 & 4 & 1\\
\end{pNiceArray}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For example it is possible to use `spalign` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[ \spalignarray{ccc|c}{5 1 5 0; 6 2 2 2; 0  3  4  1} \to\spalignarray{cc|c|c}{5 1 5 0; 6 2 2 2; 0  3  4  1}\]
\[ \spalignarray{ccc|c}{5 1 5 0; 6 2 2 2; 0  3  4  1} \to\spalignarray{cc|c|c}{5 1 5 0; 6 2 2 2; 0  3  4  1}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}

\[ \spalignarray{rrr|r}{-5 1 5 0; 6 -2 2 -2; 0  3  4  1} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example it is also possible to use `tabularray` package (version 2022A or newer) with library `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{+pmatrix}[vline{4}=solid]
5 & 1 & 5 & 0\\
6 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 3 & 4 & 1\
\end{+pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]